# $A \unlhd B, H\unlhd G \implies HA \unlhd HB$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $A,B,H,G$ are groups, with $A \unlhd B, H\unlhd G$ and $A,B,H \subseteq G$.

> Is it true that $HA \unlhd HB$?

My attempt: for $a \in A, b\in B, h \in H$ we have $(hb)(ha)(hb)^{-1}=(hb)h(hb)^{-1}(hb)a(hb)^{-1}=(hbhb^{-1}h^{-1})(hbab^{-1}h^{-1})=(*)$. Now, $h'=bhb^{-1} \in H$, $a'=bab^{-1} \in A$ $\implies (*)=hh'h^{-1}ha'h^{-1}=hh'a'h^{-1}=hh'h''a''$ for some $a'' \in A, h'' \in H$ because $HA$ is a subgroup, hence $AH=HA$.

Hence $(hb)(ha)(hb)^{-1} \in HA$, yielding the claim. Is everything ok with this proof? Do you know of any neater argument?

Comment: What is $ha$ if $h$ and $a$ aren't in the same group? Also, what does $G$ have to do with anything?

Comment: @fish Edited the question

Comment: The $h$ in $ha$ shouldn't be necessarily the same as the $h$ in $hb$. You should take some element $ha \in HA$ and $h'b \in HB$. (This isn't the same as your $h'$ later in your solution.)

Comment: See Lemma here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631996/quick-question-regarding-the-proof-that-the-quotient-of-a-soluble-groups-is-solu/3632035#3632035